# Accessing Request Object in Viewset and Serializers in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to access the request object in my Views.py and Serializers.py in DRF. 
My Views.py:

```
class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):

    """
    This viewset automatically provides `list` and `detail` actions.
    """
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer(context={'request': request})
```

My Serializers.py:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    get_sr_price = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_sr_price_func')

    def get_sr_price_func(self, obj):
        return self.request.user ??

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = (
            'title', 'slug', 'product_stores', 'get_sr_price')
```

In Serializers.py I get `ProductSerializer' object has no attribute 'request'`. Also In views.py I get `NameError: name 'request' is not defined`

How do I access request object? Do I have to pass it from views to serializers? Also what's the difference between views.py and serializers.py? Generally I write all the business logic in Views.py ; here also should I do all the queries/filters in the views or should I do them in serializers or it doesn't make a difference. New to DRF please help.

Comment: DRF includes `request` object by default in the context. Use `self.context['request'].user`.

Comment: This works. Add it as an answer will accept.

Comment: self.context['request'] not only user object you can access whatever you want from request object. exa - self.context['request'].data or self.context['request'].query_params.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You don't need to include `request` object in the context as the generic views passes `request` object to the serializer context.

**DRF Source code snippet:**

```
# rest_framework/generics.py
def get_serializer_context(self):
    """
    Extra context provided to the serializer class.
    """
    return {
        'request': self.request, # request object is passed here
        'format': self.format_kwarg,
        'view': self
    }
```

In your serializer, you can **[access](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context) the `request` object using `.context` attribute.**

> The `context` dictionary can be used within any serializer field logic,
>   such as a custom `.to_representation()` method, by accessing the
>   `self.context` attribute.

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    get_sr_price = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_sr_price_func')

    def get_sr_price_func(self, obj):
        return self.context['request'].user # access the request object
```

Answer (score 1):

Serializers are the way external data is mapped from / to models (Django or simple Python classes).

Views are dealing with how the data will be shown. Throttling, pagination, authentication are managed by the view. They also handle the data set.

DRF provides a [context](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context) to pass request specific data to the serializer without having to redefine the init. This is likely what you're looking for.

Comment: Tried passing context from views `serializer_class = ProductSerializer(context={'request': request})` it says `NameError: name 'request' is not defined`

Comment: serializer_class is supposed to be a class, not an instance.

Comment: You should override the view's `get_serializer_context`

Comment: I did `def get_serializer_context(self):
        context = {'request': self.request}
        return context`
Getting error `NameError: name 'request' is not defined`

Comment: According to https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/7351a3f6ca7028868a79a6f2dae36ccb2fc7dd65/rest_framework/generics.py#L131 you should already have the request in the serializer's context so you won't need to override the `get_serializer_context` in the end.

Comment: But how to access the request object in serializer is the question? `request.user` throws error `NameError: name 'request' is not defined`.

Comment: From the documentation link in the answer: "The context dictionary can be used within any serializer field logic, such as a custom .to_representation() method, by accessing the self.context attribute."

Comment: So it'll be self.context['request']