# Key error 'request' in serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to get the current user in my serializer, to evaluate a condition (did user like this post?), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34617511/4937981) is what I tried but it doesn't seem to work:

```
def current_user(self):
    return self.context['request'].user

class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    liked = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_liked(self, obj):
        return str(current_user(self))

    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = ('foo', 'liked')
```

And my very simple view:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def post_item(request, pk):
        serializer = PostSerializer(post)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

When trying to `get_liked` this is error is raised:

> KeyError at /api/posts/1
>
> 'request'

Am I missing something here?

Comment: You misspelled "liked" here: `def get_lked(self, obj):`. Try doing this: `def get_liked(self, obj):`

Comment: @jape That typo is not in my code, so it must have happened while typing the question. Fixed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can send the context from your view to the serializer like this:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def post_item(request, pk):
    serializer = PostSerializer(track, context={'request': request})
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Now I feel very stupid, I can't believe I missed something this obvious.

Comment: Don't! It happens!

Comment: I feel just like @SebastianOlsen, because I cannot find this in the documentation. Where is this explained in the docs?